# What is a good free library for editing MP3s/FLACs?

Tags: audio

What is a good free library for editing MP3s/FLACs.

By editing I mean:

- Cutting audio file into multiple parts
- Joining multiple audio files together
- Increase playback speed of file without affecting the pitch (eg. podcasts up to 1.3x)
- Re-encoding audio file from Flac -> MP3 or vice versa

I don't mean software, I mean a library that I can use within another application. Programming language agnostic.

Comment: Another question has been posed that also touches upon what I was after. [crop-mp3-to-first-30-seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890/crop-mp3-to-first-30-seconds)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just about every language has bindings to C, so you'll probably want to get the applicable C libraries for encoding/decoding mp3's and FLAC files. This list might include

libFLAC http://flac.sourceforge.net/api/index.html  FLAC encoding/decoding
LAME http://lame.sourceforge.net/index.php MP3 encoding
MAD http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/ MP3 decoding

The rest of your signal processing needs could be gathered around a single popular API such as LADSPA http://www.ladspa.org/.

Here's a stretching / pitch shifting library: http://www.breakfastquay.com/rubberband/

Most audio processing programs have a certain internal format they use. That keeps things simple. Everything coming in gets converted to the same format. Once you've standardized the internal format, cutting and splicing audio data is about as difficult as cutting and splicing strings. You don't really need a library for that.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) for all my editing needs

> Audacity is a free, easy-to-use audio
>   editor and recorder for Windows, Mac
>   OS X, GNU/Linux and other operating
>   systems. You can use Audacity to:
>
> ```
> * Record live audio.
> * Convert tapes and records into digital recordings or CDs.
> * Edit Ogg Vorbis, MP3, WAV or AIFF sound files.
> * Cut, copy, splice or mix sounds together.
> * Change the speed or pitch of a recording.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Audacity uses the [Lame library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAME), however not only is this not language agnostic it also has some questions over licensing. Nevertheless it might be a start