# is there a good library out there that will split a mp3 with php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mp3

So i have an application takes a uploaded song and allows the user to purchase it. I would like to also create a 30 second clip that the user can preview, but rather then having the user upload two files I want the application to create the 30 second mp3 file based on the original mp3. I found this [library](http://www.phpkode.com/scripts/item/cmp3split/) which i am using like this

```
    $oSplit=new CMP3Split(DIR_DOWNLOAD ."Made_To_Love.mp3",243,DIR_DOWNLOAD ."clips/{$rndString}.mp3",30,0);
```

but it seems to not always produce a 30 second clip

and i also found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890/crop-mp3-to-first-30-seconds) which is using ffmpeg which i dont know how to use in a php setting.

Any ideas or suggestions

Answer (score 1):

That library is largely useless: it doesn't actually even read the MP3's bitrate to figure out how much of the file to output.

Take a look at this: http://www.sourcerally.net/Scripts/20-PHP-MP3-Class

That class should be able to extract with something like this:

```
  header('Content-type: audio/mp3');
  header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="preview.mp3"');
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
  include_once('mp3.php');
  $path = '<filename to path>';
  $mp3 = new mp3($path);
  $mp3_1 = $mp3->extract(0,30);
  header('Content-length: ' . sizeof($mp3_1->str));
  echo $mp3_1->str;
```

You can expect it to be slow, and consume a lot of memory: you're probably better off using something like ffmpeg to do the chop.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the ffmpeg solution from the command line, if you get it working just call it at the command line from within PHP. `shell_exec()` can do this. If you're allowing the user to specify a file name you will want to escape the shell arguments.

Since this will take a moment, it may be wise to look into passing this work off to a queue system like gearman.

Comment: This would work well if the site is low traffic.  Just always make sure to escape the data going in.  (they name an upload `rm / -rf` haha)  This sql injections for command line.