# How can I remove silence from an MP3 programmatically?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, ffmpeg, mp3, sox

I have MP3 files that sometimes have silence at the end.  I would like to remove this silence automatically.  From what I can tell, it is "perfect" silence (0 amplitude), not background noise.  The length of the content and the silence varies.

I found some other questions about [cropping to the first 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890/crop-mp3-to-first-30-seconds) or [cropping to X and X+N seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390731/how-to-crop-a-mp3-from-x-to-xn-using-ffmpeg) using `ffmpeg`.  I would think I could use a similar approach, as long as I have a way to find when the silence starts.  How would I do that programatically?

For example, one possible solution would be to have a command that finds the beginning of the "silence".  I'd expect a sequence like this

```
end=$(ffmpeg some-command-to-find-start-of-silence)
ffmpeg -t "$end" -acodec copy -i inputfile.mp3 outputfile.mp3
```

The solution does **not** have to use `ffmpeg`, but it does need to be available on Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you truly only interested in perfect silence?  That's very rare, with dithering from 24-bit masters, and lossy compression.  FFMPEG is the way to go, in any case.

Comment: @Brad We're basically working around a bug in a recording service we use.  It seems to always give this "perfect" silence when the problem occurs.

Comment: Sounds like you might be interested in the [`silencedetect` FFmpeg audio filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#silencedetect).

Comment: @blahdiblah That might just do it.  Could you turn that comment into an answer, please?

Answer (score 46):

```
sox inputfile.mp3 outputfile.mp3 silence 1 0.1 0.1% reverse silence 1 0.1 0.1% reverse
```

This will trim any silence longer than 0.1 second from your file. If you're only concerned about trimming the end, this can be simplified to:

```
sox inputfile.mp3 outputfile.mp3 reverse silence 1 0.1 0.1% reverse
```

A detailed look into how `sox`'s `silence` works can be found [here](http://digitalcardboard.com/blog/2009/08/25/the-sox-of-silence/).

Comment: The solution works, but your explanation is wrong. The original author said 'trim silence (anything less than 1% volume) until we encounter sound lasting more than 0.1 seconds in duration.'.

Answer (score 12):

You probably are looking for a **lossless** solution, i.e. one that does *not require re-encoding* (which reduces quality).

I believe [mp3splt](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/home.php) is what you are looking for. It can be used from command line and GUI.

```
sudo aptitude install mp3splt mp3splt-gtk
```

should work on Debian and Ubuntu.

From the man page:

> You  can  also  try  to split files automatically with silence detection (see -s option), **trim files using silence detection** (see -r option), or by a fixed time length (see -t option)

Comment: What about silence in the middle of the file?

Comment: Yes but split produce multiple files, I need to remove all silence from one file.

Comment: Join them back afterwards?

Comment: Just cut dead silence in my lecture records - this silence was added by a hardware problem.

Comment: Then splitting the file, and joining sounds exactly right, doesn't it?

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at the [`silencedetect` FFmpeg audio filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#silencedetect):

> Detect silence in an audio stream.
>
> This filter logs a message when it detects that the input audio volume is less or equal to a noise tolerance value for a duration greater or equal to the minimum detected noise duration.
>
> The printed times and duration are expressed in seconds.

It has parameters to adjust how quiet something has to be to be considered silence, and how long the silence needs to be to be noted.

Comment: The `silenceremove` filter is documented here https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-silenceremove This answer might prove useful too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29411973/1717535

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert, thanks for a valuable comment. Actually it should be an accepted answer :)