# using FFMPEG with silencedetect to remove audio silence

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I am trying to use the following command with the latest ffmpeg build to remove silence from my .mp3 files:

```
ffmpeg -i SILENCE.mp3 -af silencedetect=n=-50dB:d=1 -y -ab 192k  SILENCE_OUT.mp3
```

However, the following output is produced:

```
ffmpeg version N-66154-g1654ca7 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Sep  5 2014 22:10:38 with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-lib
modplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrw
b --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinge
r --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --en
able-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis
 --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-
libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
  libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavformat    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
Input #0, mp3, from 'SILENCE.mp3':
  Metadata:
    title           : Snowblind (Featuring Tasha Baxter)
    artist          : Au5
    album           : Snowblind (Featuring Tasha Baxter)
    genre           : Electronica
    performer       : Au5
    track           : 1/1
    date            : 2014
    album_artist    : Au5,Tasha Baxter
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    encoder         : Lavf55.42.100
  Duration: 00:05:50.80, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
Output #0, mp3, to 'SILENCE_OUT.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TIT2            : Snowblind (Featuring Tasha Baxter)
    TPE1            : Au5
    TALB            : Snowblind (Featuring Tasha Baxter)
    TCON            : Electronica
    TPE3            : Au5
    TRCK            : 1/1
    TDRL            : 2014
    TPE2            : Au5,Tasha Baxter
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    TSSE            : Lavf56.4.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[silencedetect @ 0000000004398f40] silence_start: -0.00628118
[silencedetect @ 0000000004398f40] silence_end: 3.21413 | silence_duration: 3.22
041
[silencedetect @ 0000000004398f40] silence_start: 343.844
[libmp3lame @ 00000000043b2940] Trying to remove 1152 samples, but the queue is
empty
size=    8223kB time=00:05:50.79 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s
video:0kB audio:8222kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
overhead: 0.011485%
```

The generated audio file however still has the original length without any silence removed.
See the following images:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/nVxe5lX.png]

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Alright, silence detect is only DETECTING the silence. Not removing it. I will try to post a solution for this.

Comment: if anyone is interested in removing silence from video files you may find my [vwrt](https://pypi.org/project/vwrt/) package useful

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use the `silenceremove` filter. **This removes silence from the audio track only - it will leave the video unedited, i.e., things will go out of sync**

Its arguments are a little cryptic.

An example

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af silenceremove=1:0:-50dB output.mp3
```

This removes silence

- at the beginning (indicated by the first argument `1`)
- with minimum length zero (indicated by the second argument `0`)
- silence is classified as anything under -50 decibels (indicated by `-50dB`).

Documentation:
[FFMPEG silence remove filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silenceremove)

Also anyone looking to find the right value to classify silence as may wish to look into normalising their input audio volume to `0dB` first, to do this in ffmpeg see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/323119/how-can-i-normalize-audio-using-ffmpeg).

**Edit**

As pointed out by @mems, to detect whether your version of ffmpeg has the filter run

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -filters | grep silenceremove`

if you have the filter it'll output something like

`silenceremove A->A Remove silence`

Comment: To know if this filter is available: `ffmpeg -hide_banner -filters | grep silenceremove` should display `... silenceremove    A->A       Remove silence.`

Comment: Please note, that `-af silenceremove` will re-encode your audio files and thus change bitrate. You cannot use `-acodec copy` to keep the original quality.

Comment: How do you remove silence from both the beginning and end of the audio (but not the middle)? I tried following the documentation with stop_periods but it either did nothing to the file or made it corrupt with 0:00 length

Comment: how do you remove parts of a video that are silent?

Comment: Adding the detection peak should make the silence detection more dynamic, like `-af silenceremove=1:0:-50dB:detection=peak`

Comment: How to use the decoded file simply as your reference to find the silences, but perform the actual cuts on the encoded file?

Answer (score 15):

ffmpeg silence detect only detects the silence. One has to scan the ffmpeg output and cut the mp3 file.

In theory, this would be done as:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp3 -af silencedetect=n=-50dB:d=1
```

and monitoring for output in form of:

```
[silencedetect @ 0000000004970f80] silence_start: -0.00154195
[silencedetect @ 0000000004970f80] silence_end: 3.20435 | silence_duration: 3.2059
...
[silencedetect @ 0000000004970f80] silence_start: 343.84
```

And, cutting start and end silence:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp3 -ss 3.20435 -t (343.84-3.20435)
```

I ended up writing a small Java program which does it. Hints:

- ffmpeg writes to stderr. This means, you need to use ProcessBuilder and redirectErrorStream(true).
- secondly, you need to extract the silence_start and silence_end information.
- then you might use the timestamps to cut the video

Following code may be helpful:
[Using Java and FFMPEG with silencedetect to remove audio silence](http://pastebin.com/9FUisQp3)

Comment: Hi that command doesn't appear to work in the shell. What are the parenthesis doing? `$ echo ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp3 -ss 3.20435 -t (343.84-3.20435)` yields `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`('`.

Comment: You need to actually calculate the difference and then replace the expression in the parentheses with the result

Comment: you might also use `bc` (bash only does integers), so the section `(343.84-3.20435)` becomes `$(echo 343.84-3.20435 | bc)`.

Comment: Actually I get a `At least one output file must be specified` for this command.

Comment: @loretoparisi I'd say the examples are just there to show roughly how to use `-ss` and -`t`, rather than to to be used as-is.  You need to add an output file to the command line, e.g. `ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp3 -ss .... -t .... OUTPUT.wav`

Comment: @loretoparisi it should be `ffmpeg -i full-0001.wav -af silencedetect=n=-50dB:d=1 -f null -`

Answer (score 8):

After reading the FFmpeg silenceremove [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silenceremove), this is how you remove silence at the beginning and end of an audio file (keeps silence in the middle).

```
ffmpeg -i "INPUT.mp3" -af silenceremove=start_periods=1:stop_periods=1:detection=peak "OUTPUT.mp3"
```

Comment: I got an empty sound

Comment: @JRichardsz see the docs, use start_threshold, stop_threshold, or detection

Answer (score 6):

As indicated by other posters, silencedetect doesn't remove anything. To remove all silence (here lower than -30 dB) from an audio file, and leave 2 second gaps between fragments, use the following.

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp3 -af "silenceremove=start_periods=1:stop_periods=-1:start_threshold=-30dB:stop_threshold=-30dB:start_silence=2:stop_silence=2" outputfile.mp3
```

Answer (score 2):

From the following way can remove silence from the beginning and end of the file.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af "silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-50dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-50dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse" input_silence_removed.mp3
```

Comment: I got this message **Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)**

Answer (score 0):

Does anyone know how to configure a fallback so that if a DJ playing live is careless, the song ends and he starts playing silence with the encoder on for +10 seconds?
I have found a solution so that the playlist is activated if it detects that the encoder was turned off by the DJ, but I have not found a solution if the encoder continues to be on emitting silence.

This is my fallback:

```
# Fallback for live and music playlists with silence detection
radio = fallback(track_sensitive=false, [
    live,
    inv1,
    inv2,
    inv3,
    blank.strip(max_blank=10., playlist_securitized)# It will automatically switch to the playlist after 10 seconds of silence
])
```