# How to remove long silent and unchanged video sections with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video-processing

I want to identify areas in a `.mp4` (H264 + AAC) video that are silent  and unchanged frames and cut them out. 
Of course there would be some fine-tuning regarding thresholds and algorithms to measure unchanged frames.

- My problem is more general, regarding how I would go about automating this?
- Is it possible to solve this with `ffmpeg`? (preferably with C or python)
- How can I programatically analyse the audio?
- How can I programatically analyse video frames?

Answer (score 1):

For audio silence [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697596/using-ffmpeg-with-silencedetect-to-remove-audio-silence).

For still video scenes `ffmpeg` might not be the ideal tool.

You could use scene change detection with a low threshold to find the specific frames, then extract those frames and compare them with something like imagemagick's compare function:

```
ffprobe -show_frames -print_format compact -f lavfi "movie=test.mp4,select=gt(scene\,.1)"
```

`compare -metric RMSE frame1.png frame0.png`

I don't expect this to work very well.

Your best bet is to use something like [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) to find differences between frames.

[OpenCV Simple Motion Detection](https://blog.cedric.ws/opencv-simple-motion-detection)