# How to trim silence from audio with ffmpeg in php

Tags: php, ffmpeg

My hosting does not have ffmpeg's `silenceremove` filter, so I'm trying to remove the beginning and end silence of an audio file with `silencedetect` then cut.  I'm trying to do this programmatically with php.  At this point, I can't even detect the silence.  I've tried:

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/audiofiles/');
$filein = UPLOAD_DIR . "music.ogg";
$fileout = UPLOAD_DIR . "music_no_silence.ogg";
$fileouttxt = UPLOAD_DIR . "music_log.txt";
$ffmpeg = "/usr/local/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg";
```

I first tried to put the ffmpeg command into a variable and then tried to access the output but was unable:

```
$output = shell_exec("$ffmpeg -i $filein -af silencedetect=n=-50dB:d=1");
echo $output;
```

I then tried to create a.txt log of the conversion but the .txt file doesn't show anything about the silencedetect.  Furthermore, how would I be able to extract the info that I need programmatically from the .txt log in order to use it in php?

```
shell_exec("$ffmpeg -i $filein -af silencedetect=n=-50dB:d=1 $fileout 2> $fileouttxt");
```

I'm basically trying to adapt the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25698675 into php

**Edit**: Here's kind of a hack way to do it:

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/audiofiles/');
$filein = UPLOAD_DIR . "music.ogg";
$fileout1 = UPLOAD_DIR . "music_out1.ogg";
$fileout2 = UPLOAD_DIR . "music_out2.ogg";
$ffmpeg = "/usr/local/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg";
$command = "$ffmpeg -i $filein -filter_complex silencedetect=n=-10dB:d=0.5 -y $fileout1 2>&1";

$output = array();
exec($command,$output);

$searchword1 = 'silence_end';
$endmatches = array_filter($output, function($var) use ($searchword1) {return preg_match("/\b$searchword1\b/i", $var);});
$endmatches = array_values($endmatches);

$parts1 = explode(" ",$endmatches[0]);
$a = $parts1[4];
$a = $a-.5;

$searchword2 = 'silence_start';
$startmatches = array_filter($output, function($var) use ($searchword2) {return preg_match("/\b$searchword2\b/i", $var);});
$startmatches = array_values($startmatches);

$parts2 = explode(" ",end($startmatches));
$b = $parts2[4];
$b = $b+.5;

$c = $b-$a;

exec("$ffmpeg -i $fileout1 -ss $a -t $c -y $fileout2 && rm $fileout1");
```

Comment: In my installation of ffmpeg, it will prompt the user to overwrite the output file if it already exists.  Is it possible that's happening?  I don't know if there's a command line argument to force overwrite, but you could ensure the file is deleted before running ffmpeg.

Comment: The output file doesn't already exist.  Basically, what I'm trying to do is trim the beginning and ending silence from an audio file with ffmpeg and php.  Any method would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's `shell_exec` returns the output written to `stdout` and `ffmpeg` writes the messages to `stderr`. If you want to use `shell_exec` you must redirect the `stderr` output to `stdout` using `2>&1`.

You also need to specify at least one output file for `ffmpeg`, in this case `/dev/null`.

```
set_time_limit(0);

$input_file = 'music.ogg';
$cmd = "ffmpeg -i {$input_file} -af silencedetect=n=-50dB:d=1 -f null /dev/null 2>&1";
$output = shell_exec($cmd);

if (preg_match_all("/^\[silencedetect\s[^]]+\]\s([^\n]+)/m", $output, $matches)) {
    var_export($matches[1]);
}
```

An alternative is to use `proc_open` and `stream_get_contents`.