# How to trim silence and concatenate two audio files using FFMPEG in one command?

Tags: audio, filter, ffmpeg, concatenation

I'd like to trim silence from the end of audio1.wav and beginning of audio2.wav and concatenate them by adding silence of predefined duration?

---

### UPDATE

---

Following ffmpeg command add silence in between two wav files (from [answer](https://superuser.com/a/587553)):

> ffmpeg -y -i $in_wav_0 -i $in_wav_1 -filter_complex "aevalsrc=exprs=0:d=$pause[silence], [0:a] [silence] [1:a] concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[outa]" -map [outa] $out_wav

This command trims silence from the end (from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29411973/1433554)):

> ffmpeg -i input.wav -af silenceremove=1:0:-50dB input.wav

How to combine those two to commands so that concatenation would produce fixed duration silence interval in between regardless of silence present at the end and beginning of original audio files respectively? And preferably in one command.

Comment: you really should put your shoulder into this and show your work ... what have you done so far to solve this

Comment: What @ScottStensland recommended. As a bonus, have a look at SoX (http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html). Everything you need is there. If you stumble on a specific problem, do shoot.

Comment: Updated description. @ScottStensland didn't want to post the result of what i've found this far, as I suspect it can be a wrong solution. I'm new to ffmpeg and it's command-line syntax, which looks very alien to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command takes **in_a_0.wav** and **in_a_1.wav** as input and **out.wav** as output. Following command trims silence at the end and beginning from input files respectively and adds 1.5 seconds silence in between.

```
ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -y -i in_a_0.wav -i in_a_1.wav -filter_complex "[0:a] silenceremove=stop_periods=1:stop_duration=1:stop_threshold=-50dB [first], [1:a] silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=0:start_threshold=-50dB [second],aevalsrc=exprs=0:d=1.5[silence],[first] [silence] [second] concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[outa]" -map [outa] out.wav
```