# ffmpeg remove all silent parts from audio file

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, m4a

I would like to cut the silent parts (where my prof writes on the blackboard but does not talk) off from my lecture notes. I tried `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af silenceremove=1:0:-50dB output.mp3` [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697596/using-ffmpeg-with-silencedetect-to-remove-audio-silence), but it only deletes silence from the beginning of my file.

Can I delete the silence everywhere with one command? I only want the speech without all the writing on the blackboard. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Is the threshold -50dB low enough?
Also I guess "silenceremove=1" means remove only one period. Examples with more parameters use -1 to indicate an unlimited amount of periods:

http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/silenceremove.htm.gz
Or:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-silenceremove

> Trim all silence encountered from beginning to end where there is more
> than 1 second of silence in audio:

```
silenceremove=stop_periods=-1:stop_duration=1:stop_threshold=-90dB
```

(90 dB maybe is too low, depends on the noise level)

Comment: Thank you a lot. It worked very well! I did end up using `ffmpeg -i input.m4a -af silenceremove=stop_periods=-1:stop_duration=1:stop_threshold=-40dB output.mp3`, like you suggested. I just changed the threshold a bit

Comment: You're welcome! BTW, you could mark the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I would accept your answer :)