# jQuery Voice Recorder Allow michrophone

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a script that is recording my voice and I only want the recorded sound to have 30 seconds.
When I click the record button I count 30 seconds and stop the script. My problem is that I have to count those 30 second after he Allows the microphone to be on.

[image]

Is there a way to do this? If not ... What other options do I have?

Thanks

Comment: You would probably have to use some server side scripting to trim the audio at 30 seconds.. like ffmpeg [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44032/1563558)

Comment: Thank you ... Is there a way to show an alert message after he presses the Allow? ... This is what I want ... Thanks